# django redirect() with parameters

Tags: python, django

There have been several similar questions asked already but I couldn't find answer to my problem after spending loong hours.

In the code below when I redirect to "anotherView" from "myView" with parameter "username", it works fine as expected. But I need to include "range" parameter in this redirect too as this "range" is required for the template used after redirection. Whenever I try to do, I get several errors like:

-- "Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()"

Is there a way to manage this the way I want?

```
   def myView(request):
      if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
                #my code comes here
                ....
                return redirect('anotherView', username=request.user.username, {"range": range(int(layout))})



   def anotherView(request,username):
      if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #my code comes here
          ....
          return redirect(something)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`redirect` is merely a wrapper around `HttpResponseRedirect` that automatically calls `reverse` for you to create the URL to redirect to. As a result, the parameters you pass to it, aren't arbitrary, they must be same you would pass to `reverse` and, specifically, only those required to create the URL.

Many people seem to have troubles understanding that data can't just be arbitrarily passed to a view. HTTP is a stateless protocol: each request exists on it's own, as if user had never been to any other page of the site. The concept of a session was created to provide a sense of "state" to a cohesive unit such as a site. With sessions, data is stored in some form of persistent storage and a "key" to look up that data is given to the client (typically the user's browser). On the next page load, the client sends the key back to the server, and the server uses it to look up the data to give the appearance of state.

As a result, if you need data from one view available in another, you need to add it to the session, do your redirect, and look up the data in the session from the next view.

Comment: thanks for different point of view. I could use this way to solve the problem somehow.

Comment: Great! And here is the Django documentation on sessions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: I can't edit the comment on sessions by @Régis B., but the version 1.5 now gives a 404.  Here is 1.11.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 2):

Rather than redirecting to the destination url, simply call the destination view function directly:

```
def myView(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            #my code comes here
            ....
            return anotherView(request, username, range)



def anotherView(request,username,range):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #my code comes here
        ....
        return HttpResponse(something)
```

Comment: Downvoted b/c if you do it like this and someone hits the refresh button your data gets POSTed again, which is a poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect takes the name of the view to redirect to, and any attributes to be passed to the other view. In your case `anotherView` only has two parameters - request and username however in the redirect you are passing more info to it.

You can try something like:

```
def anotherView(request, username, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

That will allow you to pass more attributes to it.

Edit

How about this in the original view:

```
kwargs = {"range": range(int(layout))}
return redirect('anotherView', username=request.user.username, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I keep getting "non-keyword arg after keyword arg " or "Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()"  errors still even if I add *args, **kwargs

Comment: nope still error but different. this time redirect can't find "anotherView" view so showing "URL not found error"

Comment: @mco, if you have keyword arguments, they have to come  first, according to those errors. So you'd have to do return redirect('anotherView', username=username, item), the key being that the keyword argument (username=username) comes before the positional argument (item).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to pass the "range" variable to? anotherView? There's no parameter to accept it. I think you may be looking for the [reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: "range" variable is used in the template of anotherView. I mean when the new template is loaded after redirection, I need range there. But I don't want to put "range" variable in the URL, that's why I don't put it as a parameter of "anotherView" view. I hope I'm clear?

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the URL, but you'll need some way to accept that variable in anotherView's parameters, either by specifying it or using *args, **kwargs as miki725 suggests.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but there is a small [django_url_params](https://github.com/gkrsman/django-url-params) module for this use case now.