# Render without passing request

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

new to Django and I'm having a little trouble with this.

I have a registration form that creates rows in a database on successful submission.

Upon submission, I would like to redirect the user to a login form (which requires me to pass in the form as a parameter for render()), passing a status of '**REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL**' as a parameter as well.

```
return render(request, 'login.html', {
    'form': login_form(), 
    'status': 'REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL'
})
```

Based on the status, my template then displays a message to indicate the successful registration.

All works fine until you try to refresh the login page, it tries to submit the registration form again (I suppose because the request was forwarded to the login page).

Everything I've tried involves forwarding the request, which is proving to be a problem. Help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After form submission instead of using render, use [HTTPResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect). Always return an [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) after successfully dealing with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a user hits the Back button.

The problem that you face here is that HTTPResponseRedirect does not allow you to pass the context of the status being REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL.

> Based on the status, my template then displays a message to indicate the successful registration.

This is where you could use [Django's messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/). Right before the [HTTPResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect), you could do something like:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RegistrationForm

def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # ... do something special here if needed
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Registration was successful!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login_page'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```

Now in your "login_page", you can show the messages. FYI - the messages are on a per-session basis, so the "Registration was successful" message will only be displayed to the user you redirected:

**login_page.html:** (example from the [messages documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages))

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}    </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }} {# Your login form #}
</form>
```

In this example, any messages you added will be displayed above your login form. If there are other messages such as "invalid registration," they will be displayed.

Please be sure to [Enable the Django Messages Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages) by adding the following to your [settings.INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.messages',
)
```

And your [settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES) must contain:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

And your [settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) must contain:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much. For anyone who wants to implement the above, make sure that your settings.py file is configured properly (had that problem).

Comment: @DarylChan - I updated my answer based on your settings.py comment for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

After registration is successful, you might have to consider `redirect` which is a common practice after a successful post is done.

Django provides a short-cut for redirects.

```
return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')

return redirect('/some/url/')
```

For your case you can consider:

```
kwargs={'status': 'REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL' }

return redirect('login-view', **kwargs)
```

Comment: To clarify, this could work if his URL configuration was prepared to handle the "status" argument for the view. However, I don't care for this method, as it clutters the URL. It would show http://www.example.com/login/REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL/.

Comment: @MichaelB: NO, it won't. you are just passing parameters that could be pulled into login.html template that is being redirected to

Comment: In an attempt to make sure I wasn't wrong about reading the documentation, I tested and got the error I expected: Reverse for 'test_redirect_to' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'status': 'REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL'}' not found. According to the [redirect documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), the arguments can be a model, view name (with the arguments such as "status"), or and absolute URL.

Comment: @MichaelB: I see what you mean. but how do you see send context parameters? see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488874/django-redirect-with-parameters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488874/django-redirect-with-parameters#9489307 states that you can't, not with redirect() or HttpResponseRedirect. This is the reason that I said to use HTTPResponseRedirect then use the messaging framework to send a message to the login view. Since HTTP is stateless, you either have to pass a URL argument, and have your URLs be prepared for that argument "login/(?P<status>(...))/$" or store a variable to the user's session.  Daryl stated the issue was that the form was trying to post again on refresh, which is prevented by HTTPResponseRedirect.

Comment: @MichaelB: I agree with what you say. why is that a render does not work? when you are in log-in page, why a refresh posts the registration form again. since Http is stateless, when login form is rendered, post form data for registration should be absent?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that the user is able to hit the back button and re-post the registration form. This would not be possible if using a redirect. You raise a good point.

Comment: @MichaelB: in the question, Daryl claims refreshing the login page reposts the registration but not hitting back button which I want to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


if form1.is_valid():
            registration = form1.save(commit=False)
            registration.save()            
            messages.success(request, 'Your message here.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

in templates.
in div where you want to display the message

```
{% block message %}

   {% include "includes/messages.html"%}
{% endblock %}
```

Then create the message.html file in include folder

```
<div id="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags }} alert-dismissable">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                {{ message }}
        </div>      

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Done so your page will redirect to login page and on that page message will get display.