# Django URL not changing even after redirection

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I am new **django 1.9**. I have created a **custom Registration Page**. After doing registration, I am able to go my given redirect URL **but** URL name **doesn't** get change in URL Address Bar.

**Registration URL** - http://localhost:8000/register/add

Able to go the **template URL** but URL **not** get changed. It is same as the above "**Registration URL**"

**View.py**

```
def add(request):
       // Do something
       return render(request, 'register/index.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, use the [`redirect()` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

```
def add(request):
    # Do something
    return redirect('/register/')
```

Comment: I tried redirect() but url changes to `http://localhost:8000/register/add/register/index.html`. I need `http://localhost:8000/register/`. And also need to send parameter along with URL.

Comment: @iNikkz okay, added a sample, check it out.

Comment: Thanks. How can I send data using redirect() ?

Comment: @iNikkz please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488874/django-redirect-with-parameters. Hope these topics clear things up with redirect..

Comment: Still not get how to pass params using redirect. Can you plz edit your answer and help me out. Thanks

Comment: @iNikkz please see if it makes sense to create a separate question about redirect with parameters and how to apply it in your case. Make sure to provide all the necessary details. Thanks.